# Select max and min values on one SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table with (id, value) and I would like to get the max and min values for each id.
I have used the following without success since I got the same max and min values for every id:

```
select  max(value) as valmax,
        min(value) as valmin
from mytable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint : `GROUP BY` clause missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you find below query

```
select id,  max(value) as valmax,
        min(value) as valmin
from mytable group by id
```

Just add `group by id` in your query